# SuiteScript 2.0 Update Custom Line Field BeforeSubmit

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have customized a ready Script to get Lot Expiration Date,it is working fine in Edit mode for Old Records; but in Create Mode it will raise an Error
here is the Code:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record'], function (record) {


    function beforeSubmit(context) {

        log.debug({details: "beforeSubmit: " + context.type});

        var newRecord = context.newRecord;      

        // Check how many lines exist in the ItemFulfillment - Item sublist.
        var lines = newRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'});
        log.debug({details: "lines: " + lines}); // here I am Reading the Sublist Item Lines to Check how many lines there.
        if (lines > 0){
        for (var x = 0; x < lines; x++){
            var lotDetail = "";
            var newIventoryDetails = newRecord.getSublistSubrecord({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'inventorydetail',
                line: x
            });
            var ItemCode = newRecord.getSublistText({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'itemname',
                line: x
            });
            log.debug({details: "Item Code:" + ItemCode + " Line " + x});

        var newInvLines = newIventoryDetails.getLineCount({sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'});
          log.debug({details: "Inventory Details Lines = " + newInvLines + " lines"});
            if (newInvLines >0 ){
                for(z=0; z< newInvLines; z++){

                    var lotNumber = newIventoryDetails.getSublistText({   // getSublistValue
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                    fieldId: 'issueinventorynumber',
                    line: z
                });
                var lotQty = newIventoryDetails.getSublistText({   // getSublistValue
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                    fieldId: 'quantity',
                    line: z
                });
                var lotExpDate = newIventoryDetails.getSublistText({   // getSublistValue
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                    fieldId: 'expirationdate',
                    line: z
                });
             lotDetail = lotDetail + " lot #: " + lotNumber + " Qty: " + lotQty + " Exp. Date:" + lotExpDate + '\n';

            }        

        }
             log.debug({details: lotDetail});
          log.debug({Line: x});
        newRecord.setSublistText({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'custcol_inv_full_det',
          line: x,
            text: lotDetail
       });

    }

        }
    }       


     return {
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
     };
});
```

the error I am sure because I am updating a custom Field in Item List to Set The Text to be the full Lot Details (Lot#, Qty and Expiration Date) and Still the Main record not yet saved or created.

the Error message in Script Log

> ""Invalid API usage. You must use getSublistValue to return the value set with setSublistValue. ","userEvent":"beforesubmit","stackTrace":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)","beforeSubmit(/SuiteScripts/inventoryDetails.js:45)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}   "

how to update the custom field 'custcol_inv_full_det' beforesubmit on Create Mode?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use 'getSublistValue' instead of 'getSublistText'.  The latter may not work with all value types.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this similar issue before. Try loading the record in dynamic mode.

```
var newRecord = record.load({
    type: context.newRecord.type,
    id: context.newRecord.id,
    isDynamic:true
});
```

... then loop through the lines and now you can use `getSublistText()`